# Do I need Facebook approval for 'publish_stream ' for test users in Development mode?

Tags: facebook, testing, permissions

Facebook's documentation around the exact details of Development Mode seem sparse:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity

I have a new application. I am able to do Facebook-login through my new application, but I want to start work on posting stories to user's timelines. When I set my permission scope to

```
'publish_stream, email, user_about_me, user_birthday, user_website'
```

Not only do I receive an error message warning me that I need approval for all those other actions, but Facebook login breaks. I'm trying to figure out why, and in order to narrow down the possibilities, it would be great to know exactly what Development Mode entails.

Do I need Facebook to approve my app while it is in Development mode?

I am making a grand assumption that while in Development mode, I can ask any permission from any of my test users (or my developer users, or my admin users), and it will be granted.

Is this assumption correct?

If so, where is the documentation that explicitly and clearly states this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`publish_stream` is deprecated since a very long time. `publish_actions` is what you may need, and you do not need to get approval for any permission if you only use it for people with a role in the App (Admin, Developer, Tester).

You only need to go through the review process when you want to go online with your App - meaning, when you want OTHER users to be able to use the extended permissions.

Comment: Not only did you answer my question, you shed light on a permissions problem I would likely have had in the near future. Thank you.